# 802.11 physical mode in command line

Tags: macos, wifi, command-line

How can I find which 802.11 protocol (e.g. 802.11ac) my network card is using **from the command line**?

[This](https://osxdaily.com/2017/08/01/check-what-80211-wifi-mode-mac-using/) provides several ways of doing this using GUI utilities, but I want to be able to do it programmatically.

I have tried `airport`, `netstat`, and many other things but haven't found an option that would give me this information.

Comment: The closest you can get is `system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | grep -i "IO80211\|Firmware"`  That will give you the 802.11 "Family" and the Hardware firmware.  That family seems to be an Apple convention (12 = ac).  As for the firmware, you could always look up the specification for BCM43xx.  As for the `airport` utility, even in logger mode, it only ouputs supported `PHY Mode` in Hex.  The value I got was "31" (decimal) which doesn't translate to anything, but assume it means 802.11ac because that's what my iMac supports.  It's their software that seems to translate these values

Comment: @Allan MCS = Modulation and Coding Index (for 802.11n, ac and future), see http://mcsindex.com/ . 12 ( = 12/16) means you can use 3/4 of the physical radio bandwidth, which means "very good".

Comment: @Allan "31" is a decimal bit pattern and means here: a,b,g,n,ac, which means "a lot".

Comment: @dan So, how does one read that decimal code? The Family identifier is static - where on the mcsindex does “Family” correlate to bandwidth?

Comment: @Allan, MCS and supported physical mode are independant. For example you can get an MCS index of 12 (which is a quality of your radio environnment) when you use 801.11n or 802.11ac.

Comment: I didn't say any of that.  I'm asking how you interpreted a static value of "12" coming from the "IO80211 Family" field and equate it to the mscindex.com values in the second comment?  I can't see the "line" that connects the question to your answer so I'm looking for explanation so I can learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One correct method seems to be:

```
system_profiler SPAirPortDataType | awk '/PHY Mode:/ { print $3 ; exit }'
```

The `awk` script (between `'` ) means:

on first expression `'PHY Mode:'`, print the third field and exit the script.

Comment: Thanks to @Allan who pointed me on the right tool to start.